# difficulty using regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

Please consider the following text :

```
 String str=
            "<div style=\"text-align:left;\">$#abc#$</div>$#pqr#$";
```

How can I get the  abc and pqr.

I tried using below code

```
String tempStr =
        "$#<div style=\"text-align:left;\">$#Order-CASNo#$</div>$#abc#$";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$#)(\\w*)(?=#\\$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tempStr);

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
```

but it give me just abc..i want answer as Order-CASNo and abc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex:

**EDIT:**

```
\b(?<=\$\#)(.*?)(?=\#\$)\b
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?32kdv)**

Comment: Thanks Vishal for your quick reply.

Comment: Vishl, If i give following string its not working...      String str=
            "$#<div style=\"text-align:left;\">$#Order-CASNo#$</div>$#zzzzzzzzz#$";